# ASP.NET MVC | Edit Specific Column or Add New Entry to DB Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im following this tuturial..

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4

sadly there is no demonstration on how to add new department.

I was following that tutorial and did some of my changes too like names etc.

but now stucked as what i want to do is not avaiaible.

**Coming to Question**

I have two entities in Project Gem.Domain

1. Category.cs
2. Product.cs

with interface datasource.

```
namespace Gem.Domain
{
    public interface IStoreDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
        IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; }
        void safe();
    }
}
```

Now this in other project to which this Gem.domain is being refereced.

has the context class name as StoreDb.

```
namespace Gem.Infrastructure
{
    public class StoreDb : DbContext, IStoreDataSource
    {
        public StoreDb() : base("GemStoreConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        void IStoreDataSource.safe()
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }

        IQueryable<Product> IStoreDataSource.Products
        {
            get
            {
                return Products;
            }
        }

        IQueryable<Category> IStoreDataSource.Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return Categories;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im using structuremap.mvc same as explained in tutorial for dependency resolution.

but when i try to add new category from controller, i cant add.

Neither it understands the .Add() nor .Attach method..

My Controller Method to update the category Name.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCategoryName_DT(Category category)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Content("Not Valid");
        var updatedCategory = new Category()
        {
            CategoryID = category.CategoryID,
            Name = category.Name

        };

//For test using .Add() but not working neither do .Attach
        _db.Categories.Add();



        return Json(updatedCategory);
    }
```

[image]

Constructor in CategoriesController

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private IStoreDataSource _db;   

    public CategoriesController(IStoreDataSource db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```

one way to solve would be i guess to remove dependency resolution and do make direct object of DbStore but that wouldnt seem right..

What to do??

Comment: If you are going to use .Add() you need to pass in an argument. in your case _db.Categories.Add(updatedCategory); then after that you do _db.SaveChanges(); before returning the json. And stop doing data access stuff right in a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it turns out I manually had to define Add, Delete Attach methods in DataSource interface file.

So now it looks like:

```
public interface IStoreDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get;}
    IQueryable<Category> Categories { get;}
    void safe();

    T Attach<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

and added these methods in StoreDB (normally referred as db context):

```
public class StoreDb : DbContext, IStoreDataSource
{
    public StoreDb() : base("GemStoreConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    void IStoreDataSource.safe()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }

    IQueryable<Product> IStoreDataSource.Products
    {
        get
        {
            return Products;
        }
    }

    IQueryable<Category> IStoreDataSource.Categories
    {
        get
        {
            return Categories;
        }
    }

    T IStoreDataSource.Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        return Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    T IStoreDataSource.Delete<T>(T entity)
    {
        return Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    T IStoreDataSource.Attach<T>(T entity)
    {
        var entry = Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Finally using the Update method in controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCategoryName_DT(Category category)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Content("Not Valid");
    var updatedCategory = new Category()
    {
        CategoryID = category.CategoryID,
        Name = category.Name
        
    };

    _db.Attach(category);
    _db.safe();
       
     
    return Json(updatedCategory);
}
```

I'm not sure it's the best way. I am new to .NET and learning MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, regular routine usually looks like that:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var product = new Product("Surface", "Pro");
    context.Products.Add(product);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Sample database context:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use interface for your context, you are looking for something like this:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: oh. i want to add category not product. in tutorial it is explained how to add data to child table but not about parent. there parent was department and child was employees and a department can hold multiple employees.

Comment: @SizzlingCode this is just an example. Make sure you went through each step: 1. create context, 2. add new entity to context, 3. save changes

Comment: in my case when i try to add category using `_db.Categories.Add()` i get error which u can see in picture in my question.

Comment: @SizzlingCode try to use `IDbSet<T>` or `DbSet<T>` instead

Comment: Sir, if you see my question, i already said there that if i use db context directly which is StoreDb in my case, i might be able to add new category. 

but i have dependency resolution installed in my app cuz i followed that tutorial, its called `structuremap.mvc5` and as you can see i already have private property _db already, my controller does not need to knw the dbcontext class as its loosely coupled, i believe thats what he said in tut.

Comment: i didn't get the last part sorry. where to use DbSet<T> There is already a DbSet in StoreDb.cs file..
where to put this other DbSet??

Comment: @SizzlingCode well then use interface to inject your context dependency into your controller. See updated answer

Comment: what about IQueryable?? there would be no use of it then??
plus DbSet already in the DbContext and Adding it to interface again. wouldnt be redundant?

Comment: problem solved, answered it, but plz also see if its the right way or is there any better way to implement it.